# Получить данные из Google firebase в виде Rx

Tags: android, firebase

Итак, я умею пользоватья google firebase по гайдам с android developer, однако не нашёл никакой информации о том как получать данные из своей БД в виде Observable/Flowable в общем Rx. Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли это и если возможно то как или где взять информацию. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Firebase не предоставляет возможности делать запросы через RxJava из коробки, то вы можете сделать это вручную примерно так:

Псевдо-код на [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)

```
fun getDataWithRx() = Single.create<List<Data>> {
    firebaseInstanse.getData(object: Listener {
        fun onDataReceived(data: List<Data>) { it.onSuccess(data) }
        fun onError(error: Throwable) { it.onError(error) }
    })
}
```

Соответственно получать их как-то так:

```
getDataWithRx().subscribeBy(onNext = {}, onError = {})
```